# Оптимизация решения задачи python

Tags: python, алгоритм, оптимизация

Решил задачу, но необходимо немного оптимизировать время работы. Подскажите, как это возможно сделать?

Условие задачи:

> В строю отважной армии Сарумана друг за другом стоят  n n орков, рост
> i i-го из них равен  a i a  i ​   условных единиц. Новобранец-орк
> Гримморхус тоже собирается встать в этот строй, причём Саруману
> хочется поставить Гримморхуса на такую позицию  p p, чтобы  f ( p )
> f(p) = [количество орков левее Гримморхуса того же роста, что и
> Гримморхус] умножить на [количество орков правее Гримморхуса с ростом,
> не равным росту Гримморхуса] было максимально. Для этого Гримморхус
> может встать в начало строя, в её конец, или между любыми двумя
> соседними орками. К сожалению ни Гримморхус, ни Саруман не могут точно
> вспомнить рост Гримморхуса, у них есть только  m m предположений о
> том, каким он может быть, и для каждого из них они хотели бы знать
> оптимальную позицию, на которую Гримморхусу стоило бы встать.
>
> Описание входных данных
>
> В первой строке даны  n n целых чисел  a i a  i ​
>
> - рост орков, стоящих в строю (1  ⩽ ⩽  n , a i n,a  i ​    ⩽ ⩽  1 0 5 10  5  ). Во второй строке даны  m m целых чисел  x i x  i ​
> - предполагаемый рост Гримморхуса (1  ⩽ ⩽  m , x i m,x  i ​    ⩽ ⩽  1 0 5 10  5  ).
>
> Описание выходных данных
>
> В единственной строке выведите выведите m целых чисел - значение  f (
> p ) f(p) в оптимальной для данного роста позиции.
>
> Формат ввода
>
> 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1
>
> 1 2 1
>
> Формат вывода
>
> 8 12 8

Моё решение:

```
row = input().split(' ')
heights = input().split(' ')
result = []


def right_sum(array, index, height):
    rsum = 0
    for i in range(index, len(array)):
        if array[i] != height:
            rsum += 1
    return rsum


def left_sum(array, index, height):
    lsum = 0
    for i in range(0, index):
        if array[i] == height:
            lsum += 1
    return lsum


for height in heights:
    maxCount = 0
    for i in range(0, len(row)):
        current = left_sum(row, i, height) * right_sum(row, i, height)
        if current > maxCount:
            maxCount = current
    result.append(str(maxCount))

print(' '.join(result))
```

Comment: Ну как идея, можно сделать хешмапу где ключ - число из массива, значение - упорядоченный список индексов из массива, где это значение встречается. Тогда можно за log(k) узнать сколько таких значений слева и справа и оттуда узнать сколько остальных значений справа.

Comment: Как минимум при проходе не надо все время считать количества слева и справа, достаточно один раз посчитать количество нужных значений в строке. Дальше при перемещении вправо на один элемент просто смотреть, какой именно это элемент и получать нужные значения инкрементов/декрементом... Уже будет не O(mn^2), а O(mn)

Comment: @Harry, не совсем понял, что подразумеваете под "количество нужных значений в строке"

Comment: Ну, значение роста этого невыговариваемого...

Comment: @unpromissing А почему вы свое решение убрали? Был нормальный вопрос, а теперь нахватаете минусов или закроют за отсутствие своих попыток решения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если пройти простым алгоритмом и посмотреть, когда обновляется максимум целевой функции для каждого значения роста, то это происходит только после того, как в шеренге встретилось это самое значение. Целевая функция для других значений роста тоже изменяется, однако только в меньшую сторону. Если в шеренге встретили значение 2, то для роста 2 первый множитель целевой функции увеличился, а второй не изменился. А для роста 3 или любого, отличного от 2, первый множитель не изменился, а вот второй уменьшился.

Таким образом, в каждой точке шеренги достаточно делать проверку целевой функции только один раз - для текущего значения, и для обработки всех данных  требуется только один линейный проход.

А для быстрого расчета целевой функции нужно знать количество текущих значений слева - это накапливается в словаре currcnt, и количество отличных от текущего значений справа - это легко найти, зная длину куска справа, и разность количества текущего значения во всем списке (overcnt) и слева.
Предобработка линейная, обеспечивается O(1) для каждого вычисления целевой функции.

Итого получается **линейный алгоритм**, работает не более 0.15 с при n,m<=100000

```
import time, collections, random

n = 10
a = [random.randint(1, 5) for _ in range(n)]
m = [random.randint(1, 5) for _ in range(n)]
print(a)
print(m)
print()

def opt(a, m):
    mset = set(m)
    n = len(a)
    overcnt = collections.Counter()
    currcnt = collections.Counter()
    for x in a:
        overcnt[x] += 1
    maxes = {x:0 for x in mset}
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        currcnt[x] += 1
        if x in mset:
            t = currcnt[x] * ((n - i - 1) -  (overcnt[x] - currcnt[x]))
            maxes[x] = max(maxes[x], t)
    lst = [str(maxes[x]) for x in m]
    return(' '.join(lst))

print(opt(a, m))

[2, 4, 2, 4, 5, 1, 5, 2, 5, 1]
[3, 2, 1, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5]

0 12 3 4 0 4 4 0 4 4
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли

Comment: @vegat4 В ответе не позиция, а функция-произведение для вставки в данное место

Comment: @MBo
да уже понял

Answer (score 1):

**Представляю Вам одно из возможных решений по оптимизации Вашего алгоритма:**

```python
import numpy as np
import time

row = np.array(input().split())
heights = np.array(input().split())
result = np.zeros(len(heights), dtype=int)

def right_sum(array, index, height):
    return len(array[index:][array[index:] != height])

def left_sum(array, index, height):
    return len(array[:index][array[:index] == height])

for i, height in enumerate(heights):
    maxCount = 0
    for j in range(len(row)):
        current = left_sum(row, j, height) * right_sum(row, j, height)
        if current > maxCount:
            maxCount = current
    result[i] = maxCount

print(' '.join(result.astype(str)))
```

Предложенный оптимизированный код использует библиотеку `NumPy` для создания массивов, которые работают быстрее и используют меньше памяти, чем обычные списки в `Python`.

Было использовано булевую индексацию, чтобы найти элементы, которые не равны или равны определенному значению. Позже использовалась функция `len()` для подсчета количества таких элементов.

Далее были задействованы генераторы списков для оптимизации кода. Вместо того, чтобы создавать отдельный список для результата, формируется массив нулей, который в последствии заполняется значениями, используя цикл и функцию `enumerate()`, которая позволяет перебирать значения массива вместе с их индексами.

Также была изменена логика цикла. Вместо того, чтобы проходить по каждому элементу списка `row` для каждого элемента списка `heights`, мы проходим по каждому элементу списка `row` только один раз и вычисляем максимальное значение для каждого элемента списка `heights`.

Метод `astype()` добавлен для преобразования элементов массива в строковые значения.

Так же провел небольшой эксперимент с одинаковыми входящими данными. По его результат, выполнение алгоритма удалось `ускорить более чем в 3 раза`.

**Результат Вашего алгоритма:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Результат оптимизированого алгоритма:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По просьбе автора доработал алгоритм, без использования `Numpy`. Вышло с минимальным, но действенным вмешательством в оригинальный алгоритм. Этот код использует словарь `heights_dict` для сохранения значений `maxCount` для каждой высоты, поэтому выполнение кода становится быстрее.  Как результат новый оптимизированный алгоритм исполняется `более чем в 135 раз быстрее`, чем исходный. И в `38 раз быстрее`, чем первый вариант оптимизации.

**Новый адаптированный алгоритм без использования `NumPy`:**

```python
import time

row = input().split(' ')
heights = input().split(' ')
result = []

def right_sum(array, index, height):
    rsum = 0
    for i in range(index, len(array)):
        if array[i] != height:
            rsum += 1
    return rsum

def left_sum(array, index, height):
    lsum = 0
    for i in range(0, index):
        if array[i] == height:
            lsum += 1
    return lsum

heights_dict = {}
for height in heights:
    if height in heights_dict:
        result.append(str(heights_dict[height]))
    else:
        maxCount = 0
        for i in range(0, len(row)):
            current = left_sum(row, i, height) * right_sum(row, i, height)
            if current > maxCount:
                maxCount = current
        heights_dict[height] = maxCount
        result.append(str(maxCount))

print(' '.join(result))
```

**Результат оптимизированого алгоритма без `NumPy`:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть еще один вариант, это последняя модификация, где убраны повторяющиеся вычисления длин с помощью методов массива `array[index:]` и `array[:index]`, которые позволяют находить подмассивы с помощью срезов и тем самым еще больше ускоряют выполнение данного кода.

**Код последней модификации с срезами подмассивов:**

```python
import time

row = input().split(' ')
heights = input().split(' ')
result = []

def right_sum(array, index, height):
    rsum = 0
    for h in array[index:]:
        if h != height:
            rsum += 1
    return rsum

def left_sum(array, index, height):
    lsum = 0
    for h in array[:index]:
        if h == height:
            lsum += 1
    return lsum

heights_dict = {}
for height in heights:
    if height in heights_dict:
        result.append(str(heights_dict[height]))
    else:
        maxCount = 0
        for i in range(0, len(row)):
            current = left_sum(row, i, height) * right_sum(row, i, height)
            if current > maxCount:
                maxCount = current
        heights_dict[height] = maxCount
        result.append(str(maxCount))

print(' '.join(result))
```

**Результат последней модификации с срезами подмассивов:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я правильно понял, тут алгоритмическая сложность таккая же, только какие то более быстрые структуры данных использованы? Типа список vs массив.

Comment: Да, можна так сказать.

Comment: @M141 подскажите, пожалуйста, без использования numpy как можно оптимизировать?

Comment: @unpromissing Добавил новый вариант без `NumPy`, но лучше бы Вы не убирали алгоритм со своего вопроса. Возможно эта комплексная тема сможет в дальнейшем кому-то помочь, так же, как и Вам.

Comment: Представил еще один вариант :)

Comment: @M141 чуть позже верну оригинальный алгоритм. Ввиду возможного плагиата пришлось временно его скрыть.

Comment: @unpromissing Если мое решение помогло Вам, Вы можете отметить его, как Верное :)

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваши развернутые ответы! Но, к сожалению, моя проблема до сих пор не решена. Видимо, нужно изменить исходный алгоритм. Я попытался это сделать. Нашел индексы списка n элементов, содержащихся в списке m, но и это не помогло. Подскажите, может, есть предложения по улучшению? Ссылка на код: https://replit.com/@DurashokDurov/PY#main.py

Comment: @unpromissing К сожалению свободного времени у меня уже не осталось. Вы можете дописать, что конкретно у Вас не получается, потому что в Вашем вопросе стоит только задача оптимизации времени работы, если уж даже не учитывать, что Ваш исходный алгоритм в вопросе и код в репозитарии уже серьезно отличаются :). Таким образом, не совсем понятно, что именно Вы желаете увидеть в конечном итоге. Желаю Вам успехов в Вашем проекте. Рано или поздно у Вас все получится.